# Horizontal spacing within a Split Equation

Tags: equations, horizontal-alignment, split

I am trying to split an equation across two lines with a single \Bigg parentheses enclosing both lines. I found a way to do that using \split but there is a massive block of white space at the start of the split that I haven't been able to get rid of. Is there a way to remove that white space (or use a different combination of environments to not have it in the first place)?

```
\begin{equation*}
    d(\{2,3,4\},2) = min \Bigg( \begin{split}
        &d(\{3,4\},3) + w(3,2) = 12 + 6 = 18 \\ 
        &d(\{3,4\},4) + w(4,2) = 8 + 5 = 13 
    \end{split} \Bigg) = 13
\end{equation*}
```

The above code creates this text
[image]

Additionally while I was able to align the d's using an & when I tried to do the same with the equals at the end it didn't work and replaced the "extra alignment tab" with \cr which obviously isn't what I wanted. Is there a way to align at multiple points within a split or only one?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Just use an `array`-like environment instead of `split`.

Comment: or probably better here, `aligned` environment instead of `split`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use a `split` environment. Instead, use an `array` environment if you prefer tight line spacing or an `aligned` environment if you prefer more generous line spacing. In any case, do write `\min`, not just `min`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}  % for aligned env.
\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
    d(\{2,3,4\},2) = \min 
    \left( \begin{array}{@{}l@{}}
     d(\{3,4\},3) + w(3,2) = 12 + 6 = 18 \\ 
     d(\{3,4\},4) + w(4,2) =  8 + 5 = 13 
    \end{array} \right)  
    = 13
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
    d(\{2,3,4\},2) = \min 
    \left( \begin{aligned}
     d(\{3,4\},3) + w(3,2) &= 12 + 6 = 18 \\ 
     d(\{3,4\},4) + w(4,2) &=  8 + 5 = 13 
    \end{aligned} \right)  
    = 13
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```